# Is there any way to force Windows to map inserted USB drives using the first available drive letter?

Tags: usb

Assume the following - this assumes a Windows system with only a C drive listed within Computer/This PC:

1. I have two USB drives - both different models. For the purpose of this example, let's refer to them as "Drive A" and "Drive B"
2. I insert Drive A into the system, which is automatically assigned a mapping of "D" by Windows
3. Whilst Drive A is still connected to the system, I then insert Drive B which is assigned a drive letter of "E"
4. I then disconnect both USB drives, and reboot the system
5. Finally, I then insert Drive B back into the system

At this point, Drive B is automatically assigned a drive letter of "E" - rather than "D", which would be the first logical choice for Windows to use; it's the first drive letter that isn't currently assigned to anything. Where does Windows store information relating to previously-inserted drives and their mappings, and is there any way to override this behaviour and simply tell Windows to always mount drives using the first letter available?

Comment: Usually assigning the first available drive letter is default behavior in windows, that is strange behavior, Windows 10?

Comment: Some discussion here that may be relevant>>>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1071704/how-can-i-assign-the-same-drive-letter-for-any-usb-thumbdrive-connected?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows remembers mount points in the registry at the key of
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`:

[image]

I can suggest the hack of renaming all the entries so they they all terminate by `D:`.
Deleting them is probably just as good (do not delete the other entries).

I suggest exporting the above key to a file as a precaution, or creating a
System Restore point before starting (just in case).

For more information see
[How to Change and Assign Drive Letter in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/79064-change-assign-drive-letter-windows-10-a.html#option4).

Comment: What would happen if you renamed all the entries to `D:` and then connected two of them at the same time?

Comment: @DisenchantedLurker I tried that once. The 2nd one connected will get a random drive-letter. I can't recall if it reverted to D: after both where taken out and only the 2nd one put back. Probably not.

Comment: I would suggest using Disk Management to assigned the drive volume for the device in question, which of course changes these keys, rather then changing them manually.   I suspect in either case, if you connect multiple devices, the keys will updated due to the fact two drives cannot have the same drive letter.

Comment: @Ramhound: This method will work only for connecting one device at a time. Redoing the deletion can be by a `.reg` file that will delete drives D, E and F, which should be enough.